# HTML/PHP Email forms not functioning as wanted

Tags: php, html, email

I am doing a contact us form into my website, and i am now stuck.

Here's the PHP code:

```
#Receive user input
$Name = $_POST['Name'];
$Email = $_POST['Email'];
$Message = $_POST['Message'];
$palvelu = $_POST['palvelu'];

#Filter user input
function filter_email_header($form_field) {  
return preg_replace('/[nr|!/<>^$%*&]+/','',$form_field);
}

$Email  = filter_email_header($Email);

#Send email
$headers = "From: $Email\r\n";
$sent = mail('user@example.com', 'Yhteydenotto Pyyntö: ', $Message, $headers);

#Thank user or notify them of a problem
if ($sent) {

?><html>
<head>
<title>Kiitos yhteydenotosta!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Kiitos yhteydenotosta!</h1>
<p>Olemme sinuun yhteydessä mahdollisimman nopeasti!</p>
</body>
</html>
<?php

} else {

?><html>
<head>
<title>Jokin meni vikaan!</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Jokin meni vikaan!</h1>
<p>Emme pystyneet lähettämään viestiä?</p>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

And here's the html code of the form:

```
            <div class="col-lg-5 d-flex align-items-stretch">
                <div class="bg-white">
                    <div class="w-100 heading-title bg-primary text-center">
                        <h2 class="mb-0">Ota meihin yhteytt&auml;!</h2>
                    </div>
                        <form action="email.php" method="post" class="appointment bg-white p-4 p-md-5">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="form-field">
                                    <div class="select-wrap">
                              <div class="icon"><span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></div>
                              <select name="palvelu" id="" class="form-control">
                                <option value="">Valitse palvelu</option>
                                <option value="">Sammaleen poisto</option>
                                <option value="">Katon pinnoitus</option>
                                <option value="">Tiilikaton huolto</option>
                                <option value="">Vuosihuolto</option>
                              </select>
                            </div>
                              </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                              <input type="text" id="Name" name="Name" placeholder="Nimi" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                              <input type="Email" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="S&auml;hk&ouml;posti" class="form-control">
                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-wrap">
                                </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="input-wrap">
                                </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                              <textarea id="Message" name="Message" class="form-control" placeholder="Viesti" rows="6" maxlength="3000"></textarea>
                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                              <input type="submit" value="L&auml;het&auml; viesti" class="btn btn-primary py-3 px-4">
                            </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                  </form>
                </div>
                </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

So that's in finnish but i have this list where you can select what job you want to discuss "palvelut" and then the basic form. What it should do is to send an email with "who sent it" "the job they want" and the basic form stuff "name" "email" and the "message". But now it only seems to send an blank email with only the "yhteydenotto pyyntö" it means like "a new question". Could someone help me? What am i doing wrong...

Comment: print `$_POST["Message"]` to see if it is not empty

Comment: What do you mean?, sorry im really new to this

Answer (score 0):

Solution Here!!!
* Your filter_email_header is contain Problem so we use Default FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL filter.

Remove code

```
#Filter user input
function filter_email_header($form_field) {  
return preg_replace('/[nr|!/<>^$%*&]+/','',$form_field);
}

$Email  = filter_email_header($Email);
```

Replace the Fix

```
// Remove all illegal characters from email
$email = filter_var($email, FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
```

*Your Form select option not present value so whatare the value select empty value to shown email form

```
<select name="palvelu" id="palvelu" class="form-control">
<option value="Valitse palvelu">Valitse palvelu</option>
<option value="Sammaleen poisto">Sammaleen poisto</option>
<option value="Katon pinnoitus">Katon pinnoitus</option>
<option value="Tiilikaton huolto">Tiilikaton huolto</option>
<option value="Vuosihuolto">Vuosihuolto</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: That worked almost! It got everything else correctly, but it still isn't showing the "message" and "name" and "palvelu" aka service. In the mail?

Comment: And my machine i'm able retrive"message" and "name" but palvelu its only problem that also now fixed and updated , kindly check it

Comment: I tried putting it how i understood you put it, but for me it just looks like this? [Pictures](https://imgur.com/a/3DTAxx0) It just shows me in the mail i recieved: who i got it from and my email (aka reciever email) that i blurred. I don't understand why isn't it printing anything